# SwiftData #Predicate do not work with Date

Tags: swift-data

```
let startDate: Date = Date()
    let predicate = #Predicate<Trip> { session in
        session.startTime >= startDate
    }
```

Does anybody has this issue when #Predicate do not work on Date? I am getting unsupported predicate error. Any ideas to fix?

Comment: This is a known issue listed in the release notes: #Predicate does not support UUID, Date, and URL properties. (109539652)https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-17-release-notes

Answer (score 2):

Since date isn't yet available to be used on the `#Predicate` macro, in the meantime, the following workaround can be used:

```
@Query private var queriedTrips: [Trip]

// Create a computed property
var trips: [Trip] {
    let startDate: Date = Date()

    return queriedTrips.filter({ $0.startTime >= startDate })
}
```

While this may not be ideal, I don't think there's much we can do at the moment.